# Socket communications between Client and Server at C language

Tags: c, sockets

Good day. I'm studying C language and trying to create simple database application by using socket.
The one I'm creating is something like,,,

When I run client.exe with an argument, table name, server side program searches a file whose name is the argument and returns its content.

something like

```
D:\C practice\C_Database2\Client>client.exe T_USER
UserId,Name,deleteFLag
1,Jack,0
```

However current result is

```
D:\C practice\C_Database2\Client>client.exe T_USER
a
```

my source codes are

DBClient.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA w;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buf[256];
    char *result;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &w);

    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_port = htons(9999);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    send(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    recv(sock, result, 3000, 0);

    printf("%s", result);

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup;

    return 0;
}
```

DBServer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include "tableSelect.h"

int main()
{
    WSADATA w;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char buf[20];
    char *result;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &w);
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(9999);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
    listen(sock, 1);
    int len = sizeof(client);
    int sock2 = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);

    recv(sock2, buf, sizeof(buf), MSG_PEEK);
    result = tableSelect(buf);
    printf("%s", result);
    send(sock2, result, 3000, 0);

    closesocket(sock);
    closesocket(sock2);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

tableSelect.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tableSelect.h"

char *tableSelect(char tblName[20])
{
    static char result[3000];
    FILE *fp;
    char filePath[256];
    int chr;
    int i = 0;
    sprintf(filePath, "data/%s/%s.csv", tblName, tblName);

    fp = fopen(filePath, "r");
    while ((chr = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        result[i] = chr;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return result;
}
```

I could confirm DBServer.c could retrieve data from a file 25th rows printf("%s", result);

This is the result

```
D:\C practice\C_Database2\Server>server.exe
UserId,Name,deleteFLag
1,Jack,0
```

Questions that I would like to ask you are

1.When I change recv 3rd argument, len to 35, around actual length of result it worked, client side could receive  file content.
Why does it happen just because I changed len argument?

```
recv(sock, result, 3000, 0);
```

↓

```
recv(sock, result, 35, 0);
```

2.If I have to know the actual length of the result how should I get it before recv at client side?

I apologize for long question but I really appreciate it if you could give me tips.
Thank you so much.

Comment: When working with `SOCK_STREAM` **always** check the number of bytes sent or received, as they may be less than expected. If so, you can loop and repeat (google for `recv_all / send_all`). Not sure if there are other issues in your code, but his one is important.

Comment: The important point is that tco is a stream of bytes. You cannot assume that if you send 10 byes that you will receive them all at once

Comment: Thanks for your advices and I'm so sorry for late response. This problem was solved. The reason of this error was due to unassigned memory to result valuable in DBClient.c. When I allocate memory by using malloc I could confirm it works.